# Como salvar texto formatado no banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados

Estou utilizando o TinyMCE para edição de textos no meu site. Porém, estou com dúvida para salvar o texto formatado no banco de dados e depois exibi-lo da forma que o usuário digitou. (parágrafos, cor da fonte,etc). Há alguma forma de fazer isso? Estou utilizando asp.net mvc com sql server de banco de dados.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nos meus projetos, anoto o campo de texto com HTML da seguinte forma nos *Models*:

```
    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Description", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public String Description { get; set; }
```

Pra exibição, use na *View*:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Description)
```

Comment: Obrigado brother, mas isso é o suficiente para exibir o mesmo texto também?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.